# R (data.table): number of different values of variable using combination of key variables between two data.tables, while avoiding massive join

Tags: r, join, bigdata, distinct-values

I have two massive datasets which have three variables in common (`a`, `b`, `c`). The first dataset contains two other variables (`d` and `e`) while the second dataset contains one additional variable (`f`). I would like to know how many different values of `e` there are for different combinations of `a`, `d` and `f`.

The simplest way would be, first, to merge the two datasets; then to count the number of different values of `e` for unique combinations of `a`, `b`, `d` and `f`. Below is a simple code example.

```
df1 = data.table(a = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
                 b = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
                 c = c(3, 4, 3, 4, 7, 8),
                 d = c(100, 100, 200, 200, 100, 100),
                 e = c(1000, 1000, 900, 901, 1000, 1000))

df2 = data.table(a = c(1, 1, 1, 1), 
                 b = c(2, 2, 2, 2),
                 c = c(3, 4, 7, 8),
                 f = c(500, 600, 500, 500))
```

The code below would give us the desired output:

```
> df_join = df1[df2, on=.(a,b,c), allow.cartesian = TRUE]
> df_join
   a b c   d    e   f
1: 1 2 3 100 1000 500
2: 1 2 3 200  900 500
3: 1 2 4 100 1000 600
4: 1 2 4 200  901 600
5: 1 2 7 100 1000 500
6: 1 2 8 100 1000 500
> df_join[, .(n_e=.N), by=.(a, b, d, f)]
   a b   d   f n_e
1: 1 2 100 500   3
2: 1 2 200 500   1
3: 1 2 100 600   1
4: 1 2 200 600   1
```

I don't manage to construct the object `df_join` with my real data given that it is massive (note that I added `allow.cartesian = TRUE` in the code). I get the following error:

```
Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin || !anyDuplicated(f__,  : 
  Join results in more than 2^31 rows (internal vecseq reached physical limit). Very likely misspecified join. Check for duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try by=.EACHI to run j for each group to avoid the large allocation. Otherwise, please search for this error message in the FAQ, Wiki, Stack Overflow and data.table issue tracker for advice.
```

I am trying to come up with a more efficient code given that I don't need the full list of `e` but just the number of different values by the set of variables `a`, `b`, `d` and `f`. The main challenge is that I `c` needs to enter the code somehow because it is one of the key variables that should be used to match the rows in the two datasets. I am not sure if `by=.EACHI` could be of use here.

Comment: Thank you @akrun. I forgot to mention I have indeed added `allow.cartesian = TRUE` in my original code and the error persists - I have edited the code above to reflect this.

Comment: @akrun thanks for picking this up - it was incorrect indeed. I have just edited my example above.

Comment: Thank you @akrun! When applying it to my real data I get the following error: `Error in `[.data.table`(df_join, rep(seq_along(hosp_id_list), lengths(hosp_id_list))) : 
  long vectors not supported yet: memory.c:3846`

Comment: In that case, probably you can split the data into a block of groups, loop over the list, apply the code, and combine the summarised output into a single one, while removing the intermediate objects from memory

Comment: i.e. `n <- 3` (modify this value based on the size of your original data);  `lst1 <- split(df1, as.integer(gl(nrow(df1), n, nrow(df1))));out <- vector('list', length(lst1));for(i in seq_along(lst1)) {tmp <- lst1[[i]][df2, on = .(a, b, c), allow.cartesian = TRUE]; out[[i]] <- tmp[, .(n_e = .N), by = .(a, b, d, f)]; rm(tmp)};  na.omit(rbindlist(out))[, .(n_e = sum(n_e)), .(a, b, d, f)]`